# php5: string inside a pattern to use for preg_match

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.6

I am using php5 and using preg_match() to extract data on match. 
I have a string formed using sprintf and is as :

```
$name = sprintf("sda%d", 0);
```

This name has be a string to search in pattern defined as:

```
$pattern='/$name ([^\/]*)/';
```

The $pattern is used in preg_match to get data from sda0 string to / token.
When I printed the $pattern I am getting output as */$name ([^/]*)/*. But I am expecting the output of pattern to be */sda0 ([^/]*)/*.

Can anyone help me how to use the string inside a pattern string?

Regards,
Sowmya

Comment: use `$pattern="/$name ([^\/]*)/";` or `$pattern='/'.$name.' ([^\/]*)/';`. variables are not parsed on single quotes (only on double quotes)!

Answer (score 1):

`$name` will not get data if `'` single-quote is used.

Try with double-quotes: `$pattern = "/$name ([^\/]*)/";`

Comment: @AkhilVL - see comment on question! I think that's a basic php problem and no answer needed!

Comment: Thank you Akhil for the answer.